# How do I unlock officer cards in Dynasty Warriors Next?

Tags: dynasty-warriors-next

I've recently picked up a PS Vita along with the game Dynasty Warriors Next. In DWN, there is a campaign mode that unlocks officer cards to make your officers playable. However, there are quite a few other cards that can be unlocked, but I don't know how.

Can anybody tell me how to unlock those?

Note: I looked on google, but my answer was not there.

Comment: never mind just figured it out ;).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is only one practical way to unlock characters, and that is Conquest mode.

E.g. Your group say Wei vs Other, and you notice there is a number `#/14`. The `#` represents the amount of characters you have already unlocked. If you go to battle over a territory and you end up fighting a character you don't have, you have a chance to unlock them. For all groups, Shu, Wu and Wei, you unlock 16 in the campaign. I think 2 for Jin and 2 for Other. There are 2 sets to every character, the 1st of which is normal and a 2nd which has different clothes, stats, abilities and units.

Good Luck with the card collecting